# Mysql error #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have the following `stored procedure` in `mysql`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_patient`(IN `name` VARCHAR(45), IN `surname` VARCHAR(45), IN `middle_name` VARCHAR(45), IN `patient_gender` VARCHAR(15), IN `patient_weight` VARCHAR(15), IN `patient_height` VARCHAR(15), IN `patient_ethnic_origin` VARCHAR(45))
    NO SQL
BEGIN

BEGIN
INSERT
INTO
  patient(
    name,
    surname,
    middle_name
  )
VALUES(
  name,
  surname,
  middle_name
) ;
SELECT
  LAST_INSERT_ID() AS patient_local_id;
END;
BEGIN
INSERT
INTO
  demographics(
    patient_id,
    gender,
    weight,
    height,
    ethnic_origin
  )
VALUES(
  patient_local_id,
  patient_gender,
  patient_weight,
  patient_height,
  patient_ethnic_origin
) ;
END;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I'm trying to execute this stored-procedure from `phpmyadmin` I get the following error:

```
Unrecognized keyword. (near "ON" at position 25)
SQL query: Edit Edit

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;

MySQL said: Documentation

#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

Comment: The line from the error message appears nowhere in your stored proc, at least not in the code which you actually showed us.  But, you should use `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Do I have to include `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1` in my stored-procedure code?

Comment: Well, are you already doing this in your proc code?  The error message seems to be yes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't have it in my proc code. Maybe it's something that happens by default?

Comment: `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;` isn't valid MySQL AFAIK.  Something must be inserting this code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can I modify my proc in some way to be executed properly?

Comment: Who is calling `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS`?  You seem to either not want to tell us this, or you don't know.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. When I was executing the stored-procedure I had the following box checked.

[image]